# Core Data: sorting by date attribute in a to-many relationship

Tags: ios, iphone, sorting, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have the following model:

```
  Entities:  Entity <----------->> SubEntity
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Attributes:  >name                 >uuid
             >identifier           >date
```

**Problem #1:**
I have a fetch request for `Entities`.  I want to sort the fetch by the latest `date` of all the `SubEntities` in each `Entity`.  How would I do that?

**Problem #2:**
Furthermore, the fetch request has `resultType = NSDictionaryResultType` and in the returned dictionary, I would like to fetch the properties `name` and `latestDate` (the latest `date` of all the `SubEntities` in that `Entity`).  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion for you would be to change your model:

Add a `latestDate` property to `Entity`
When updating a `SubEntity`.`entity` property, check if the `SubEntity` `date` is the latest for this `Entity` object and update accordingly.

This will allow you to accomplish what you need with a simple query, and you will then be able to use a fetched results controller to track your data changes.

If you cannot restructure your model, look at @Michal K's answer, but prefetch ALL your `Entity` and `SubEntity` object (2 requests), and only then use his algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem #1**

I do not think you can do that using `NSSortDescriptor` on collection relationship. You could do subqueries on it, but they only filter objects; they do not sort them.

I would recommend you the following approach:

Firstly pick `SubEntity` with latest date (max) for each `Entity`:

```
NSArray *entities = ... // fetch here all your entities

NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Entity *entity in entities) {
  SubEntity *max = [[entity subEntities] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.date"];
  if (max) [result addObject:max];
}
```

then simply order `result` array:

```
id sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
result = [[result sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]] mutableCopy];
```

and you will end up with a collection of `SubEntity` objects sorted by date.
You can directly access `Entity` from `SubEntity`.

**Problem #2**

As far as I know you cannot do that that way. You can access these elements using the solution above.

Comment: This will fault in the entire dataset (if you have N `Entity`s and M `SubEntity`s you will have 1 large trip to the store to fetch all N entities and then M trips to the store to fetch each sub-entity ==> O(M) trips to the store) ==> very bad performance

Comment: When a fault is fired, Core Data does not go straight to the store if the data is available in its cache or if it is prefetched. As the question does not specify the size of data, nor it asks for the best performance, I preferred to keep these details out of my answer.